# Should we set SDK level as 22 for Android? (react-native)

Tags: react-native

In official react-native documents.

Android SDK level is set to 22(Marshmallow). 
Is this recommendation or limitation? or the documents are just outdated?

I'm asking this because it seems kind of low in nowadays. And it means that we can't use Android's new feature.

Can I just change the SDK level? Is there anyone tried it?

I used Xamarin.Forms too and they support a new SDK very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently using sdk 26. You can use any sdk you like.